# How to use Puppetter with express API and properly closing the browser without affecting other concurrent request

Tags: express, puppeteer

I have a website which has some data as HTML (loaded via ajax) and I have to convert that to JSON with custom formatting.

So, for this I choose Puppeteer.

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: true, args: ['--no-sandbox']
        });
const page = await browser.newPage();
```

This web API that I'm developing will be having concurrent web requests, so I thought `browser.close()` might affect the other concurrent requests, so I decide to do only `page.close`.

One problem that I'm facing is when I do `puppeteer.launch`, for each request it opens two `about:blank` tab in a new window.

And when `browser.newPage()` is requested it returns one of the blank tabs and leaves the other one opened.

That leads to multiple window opened with multiple `about:blank`.

Here I don't know the right way to handle this, I can't close the browser because it will close all the pages which are being used by other requests.

Comment: Wait - are you opening a new browser for each request?

Comment: @Vaviloff yes I'm opening and closing for each request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing an empty (`about:blank`) tab each time you run this code, because you are doing two things here:

1. Launching a new browser - *which already starts with an open tab*

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: true, args: ['--no-sandbox']
        });
```

2. Opening a new tab.

```js
const page = await browser.newPage();
```

If you don't want to have "zombie" blank tabs, then you can just reuse the initial tab like this:

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: true, args: ['--no-sandbox']
        });
const currentPages = await browser.pages(); // list the opened tabs
const [page] = currentPages; // use the first (and only) opened tab.
```

Note that in this case, since you are just reusing the only one and initial tab, closing it with `page.close()` will have the same effect as closing the browser with `browser.close()`.

### Exploring some Express + Browser concurrency alternatives

Consider that a different solution would take place if you want to reuse the same browser instance for the lifetime of your Express server, ie. serve all requests on the same browser, or if you want to use a new browser instance for each individual request.

#### 1. One browser instance per server

In this case it *might* make sense, depending on your requirements, in managing one *tab* per request.

```js
// launch the browser instance, once
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: true, args: ['--no-sandbox']
        });

// handle incoming requests
app.get("/foo", async (req, res) => {
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  try {
    // ... execute some logic on this new page
  } catch(error) {
    // whoops, logic went wrong, respond with 500 or something
  } finally {
    // cleanup: close the opened tab, no matter how the logic resulted
    await page.close()
  }
})
```

Note that still in this scenario, the browser context would be shared across the pages, for example cookies, local storage, and so on. You have to consider this if you plan to allow concurrent requests that also can have conflicts in reusing the same shared context.

#### 2. One browser instance per request

In this scenario you launch a new browser instance per request, you ensure each request will have a clean context and won't collide with other possible requests.

```js
app.get("/foo", async (req, res) => {
  // launch the browser instance, one per request
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: true, args: ['--no-sandbox']
        });
  // no need to open a new tab, reuse the first one
  const [page] = await browser.pages(); 

  try {
    // ... execute some logic on the page
  } catch(error) {
    // whoops, logic went wrong, respond with 500 or something
  } finally {
    // cleanup: close the browser
    // await page.close() // (not really needed if you will close the entire browser, 
                          //  and would have the same effect as browser.close() 
                          //  if you haven't opened more tabs)
    await browser.close()
  }
})
```

But consider that spining a new browser process up would also be more resource-intensive, and your request would take more time to resolve, compared to reusing an already available browser process.

**EDIT**: code formatting.